# PHP Sessions versus POST resubmission

Tags: php, session, post

I'm polishing and getting my first application ready for production when I started doing some research on optimizations. In our application (as tested) the average user sends 7 requests to the server per minute.

The application is set up to use a randomly generated key for validation. If at any time the user's validation key does not match the key in the database, the key is changed again and the user is logged out of the application. Due to the nature of the application, going "back" on the app won't change or break the validation key, so that's never an issue. The only way for the validation key to be incorrect is somebody else logging into your account, somebody trying to jack the login session.

There's a lot of posts on the interenet, some of them are shaming the use of `$_SESSION` variables, and some of them are praising them. Some of them are saying that there's no harm in usage, and some are saying that it adds quite a bit of response time to the requests. The only data that needs to be stored in the `$_SESSION` in my case is an Integer and a UUID.

I'm trying to figure out if sending these variables to the server from the client (and sending the updated UUID back to the client) every request would be more efficient then loading and storing the UUID from a PHP session every request.

As I had said before, there's an enumerous amount of posts on the internet that have conflicting information and most of them are from years ago, and considering technology changes with time, I figured it would be worth asking here in 2015.

Comment: `"7 requests to the server per minute"` is absolutely nothing in terms of load. How large are these requests and how many said users would be accessing your application at any given time?

Comment: Any answers you get are likely going to be based on opinion and not fact. The difference between the two is sending the key with the body of each request/response back and forth or just storing it on the server and reading from disk (using the default implementation of sessions, but this could be switched to use redis or mysql pretty easy for faster access if this becomes a bottleneck) along with sending a token in a cookie back and forth.

Comment: @Darren - Requests include picture uploads, picture downloads, and basic information requests from a database.  (IE: Pulling a paragraph of text, or a few integer values).  The most common request (Executed around 4 times) a second downloads 5 pictures with about 20 String objects for profile display. BETA active user count has stuck around 600 concurrent users (online).  Can't guarentee release numbers, but I figure 2k CCU would be a fair assumption after a week or two of ads.